# Trouble with user inputs

Tags: python, list

In my code I am trying to make an etch-a-sketch. I am in a coding class at my highschool and our project is to use lists and user inputs to make whatever we wanted to do. I chose etch-a-sketch because our class is also doing drawing with turtles. Currently I have a turtle (`trtl`) and a user input. Here is how I have it set up

```
user_inp = [] 
x = input(" ")
user_inp.append(x)
```

I am trying to have it read through the code as if you'd read a book and not just search for 1 variable at a time. currently I have a def function set as

```
def move():
  trtl.forward(20)

for w in user_inp():
   if w in user_inp:
       move()
```

The problem with that is that is say I put in "w w" as my input. It doesn't work and instead it shows up as nothing. I need help quite badly and when I tried explaining what I needed help on to my teacher he didn't understand. If any of you do and can help me please do so.

Comment: change `user_inp.ammend(x)` to `user_inp.append(x)`

Comment: `user_inp.ammend(x)` should give you `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ammend'`. You should see this error. How do you start your program?

Comment: I know its append. Idk why I had that typo

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `user_inp.ammend(x)` is a typo. Obviously `user_inp.append(x)` is what you want.

Your logic is going to cause the turtle to always move 20 steps for each and every input character. The following code assigns the new variable `w` to each successive character in the user input. It's not getting all `'w'` characters from their input:

```
for w in user_inp():
```

Similarly, now that `w` contains some character from the input, this code will always return true:

```
if w in user_inp:
```

That's because we already got the character out of the input, so it's guaranteed to be in the input.

Instead, you just have to do something like:

```
for letter in user_inp():
   if letter == 'w':
       move()
```

Comment: I tried that and it is just putting them in the same list as 1 bond? I guess you could say that, and not separating them to have w be an independent letter to be able to be counted twice

I set input as "w w"

Answer (score 0):

you need to change `user_inp.ammend(x)` to `user_inp.append(x)` and when you are looping through the `user_inp` list you don't need the parentheses because it isn't a function it is a list so that will send an error as well